# PushManager endpoint contains "undefined"

Tags: push-api, chrome-gcm

While using the `serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe` method from a ServiceWorker, the created `endpoint` sometimes contains an ***"/undefined"*** at the end of the string.

For example, through a Chrome ServiceWorker : `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/xxx...xxx/undefined`

I must say that I've got a valid *Android Sender ID*, and if remove this extra part, I'm able to **send a push to the user**.

Last but not least, this situation has happened with both **Chrome** and **Firefox** subscriptions.

Comment: Can you show us your source code? It's difficult to find out what's the problem otherwise :)

Comment: As I thought the issue was induced by the Mozilla an GCM push services, I willingly didn't paste the ServiceWorker code I'm using. But in any case, it is pretty simple : a `serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe` promise, with the `userVisibleOnly: true` in param, and of course an accessible JSON manifest with the sender ID for Chrome. Also, this event is quite sporadic (but not isolated to one domain scope), **most of the time, the endpoint is "undefined"-free**. I'm really trying to understand what could be the cause, and why both on GCM and Mozilla.

Comment: I've never experienced this issue, it would help if you could add a snippet of your code to your question, since I suspect there's something wrong with it.